# How can I split array content?

Tags: readarray

I want to draw a special chart, for which the data are given as shown in the minimal example: The first row shows years, the first column Companies and at the cross-points you find a string of data. Using the *readarray* package, I can extract each cell. Furthermore, I also want to break down the sting of data. For such a task, the *listofitems* comes along the *readarray* package.
However, I fail to do so. The (not) working examples leads to

> Paragraph ended before \dataA was complete.

Using \numberlen, which is supposed to show the number of list entries, I got 2 -- not 4.

Does anybody have a hint on a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{;}
\setsepchar{,}

\begin{document}
\def\dataF{%
;2014;2015
A;36,3,29,4;35,6,27,8
B;19,4,35,7;23,10,33,7}
\readarray*\dataF\dataA[2,2]

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \dataA[1,1] & \dataA[1,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \dataA[2,2] \\
\end{tabular}

\readlist*\numbers{\dataA[2,2]}

%\def\numbersF{\Daten[2,2]}
%\readlist*\numbers{\numbersF} % fails as well

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \dataA[1,1] & \dataA[1,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \dataA[2,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \number[1] \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, `\number` is certainly wrong: it is a TeX primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few typos, and one misunderstanding (need `\edef` rather than `\def`).

1. `\def\numbersF...` should be `\edef\numbersF...`
2. `{\Daten[2,2]}` should be `{\dataA[2,2]}`
3. `& \number[1] \\` should be `& \numbers[1] \\`

The revised MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{;}
\setsepchar{,}

\begin{document}
\def\dataF{%
;2014;2015
A;36,3,29,4;35,6,27,8
B;19,4,35,7;23,10,33,7}
\readarray*\dataF\dataA[-,2]

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \dataA[1,1] & \dataA[1,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \dataA[2,2] \\
\end{tabular}

\readlist*\numbers{\dataA[2,2]}

\edef\numbersF{\dataA[2,2]}
\readlist*\numbers{\numbersF} % fails as well

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \dataA[1,1] & \dataA[1,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \dataA[2,2] \\
    \dataA[2,1] & \numbers[1] \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the typos resulted from making the big thin small. But in the end, the \edef was the crucial point. Thanks!

Comment: @user198207 Glad I could help.